# Stream audio from PC to smartphones?

Tags: java, c#, windows, audio, streaming

For Christmas 2016, me and my dad want to do a Lightshow for our neighborhood with lights and **music**.

[image]
We have the lights set up, but the music is a problem. We don't want to put huge speakers in our garden because that would be very annoying for our densely populated neighborhood.

So, we came up with this concept:

[image]

The computer (Windows 7) handles the lights with a sequencer from Light-o-rama.

**Now my question is:**
How can I stream audio from the PC to the smartphones?
I can figure out the smartphone end myself, but the streaming audio from PC is the thing here.

The solution can be anything! But I can't seem to figure it out!
Relevant languages I can do are:

1. C++
2. C#
3. Java
4. NodeJS
5. ASP.NET

But it can also be a program that already can do this!

EDIT:
**THIS IS A MUST: Lights and music have to stay in sync! The lights dance to the music**

Anything helps! Thx in advance!

EDIT:
I have awarded the in my eyes most fitting solution to this case the bounty, however, I haven't had the time to test all of the posted solutions. I will try to try every single one of them and then select that answer as the solution! Please see my comment underneath the answer which has the bounty! Thx all for the help!

Comment: The lightshow is surely much less annoying ;) haha - I mean hohoho. Have you thought of perhaps something with [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/) would be possible?

Comment: Are you totally against streaming the audio through a radio station? That's what people in my neighborhood do. Whoever wants to listen can tune in, otherwise it's silent. I know it's a bit archaic compared to the wifi/phone combo, plus I don't know the price on obtaining temporary station rights...

Comment: I suggest using Plex. It can handle a lot more than audio. Get a projector and show some of those Christmas movies too :)

Comment: @cdomination i'm not against it, but the problem with a radio station is that you have to pre-select songs / add songs to the radio station. So let's say I have a show with lights dancing in perfect sync with a song called jinglebells.mp3. If I put that mp3 in a radio station and start the lights, how will I make sure that jinglebells.mp3 starts at EXACTLY the same time? If it doesn't, the lights and the music will be out of sync :(

Comment: @Fildor Can it be done with DLNA that the music and lights start at exactly the same time?

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, like I said, I don't really know the details, but I know it has been done before (Music and lights are always in sync). Something to think about at the very least

Comment: I don't know. It was just the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @tanikaze Hey i've tried Plex and it is a good system for sure, but it has a few disadvantages in view of my case. 1. You have to have an account to listen 2. No streaming, you can only playback audio files that were put on by the computer. Good suggestion, but considering those two points I think i will have to look elsewhere

Comment: Erik-so there must be a logical syncing mechanism defined between the lights and the sounds. It could either be hardware (some kind of interface with the lights that can control when the show kicks off) or it just just be time (start at 8pm), or it could be something else like say....computer vision (smartphone camera reading a pattern on lights to trigger audio). My point is, I think you need to narrow your requirement to determine what that logic should be, before people can help you. Best bet IMHO is to see how your light-o-rama sequencer can interface with a pc, and go from there.

Comment: theoritically for the lowest delay, all smartphone must connect/ act as the speaker, then your host machine (Windows) must be able to output to all of those speakers. Another solution is that you pretty much can stream online through youtube or facebook. Let people watch that, then they are synced... with internet delay (2 secs delay fine?).

Answer (score 3):

If you can get everyone to download this app: [SoundWire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&hl=en) you can stream audio from Windows to any Android phone (assuming your friends are cool)

Check it out looks pretty cool, you can even stream a youtube video and get the audio synced up with any android smartphone

Comment: Good suggestion! It works as expected, the only downside here is that only Android devices can download the app. So depending on what kind of phones visitors have they can either listen or not be able to do so. If no other solutions come up I will do this, but I'd rather explore some more options to see if everyone can listen ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have a complete solution stack for you:

- You should use an [OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.wifidog) router to build a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiFiDog_Captive_Portal) (all http could be redirected to your url -> your audio streaming pc)
- A [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is able to [stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK2EW9j7D20) your content as you want. If you want you could start the stream from [command line](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/).

In my experience this kind of VLC stream is the most effective one, it has almost 0 delay compared to other solutions (I tried gstreamer). If you really would like to stick with **Java** you are able to use [**VLCJ**](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) which is a nice solution too.

**Extra**: also with VLC you could set up a camera in front of your house to show that in your stream too!

Comment: I'm going to try this one!

Comment: I set up the stack at home, it has got less than ~100ms delay. If you play the music this time ahead, you'll be able to create an epic show! Do you mind to accept my answer? :)

Comment: I got it working too! Great! Do you know the delay is always the same? because i get about 2s delay everytime. If it is and somehow the lights will be able to cope with that delay by scripting the music should start 2s before the lights, than I can accept your answer and it's gonna be an epic show :D

Comment: As I see it depends on the PC. On my computers the delay was constant ~100ms but it was constant. I guess the initialiasation of the component takes a bit more time, but after there was no delay I could observe.

Comment: Do the clients need to install VLC?  Does the delay depend on the client's device or the source device?  I believe this solution is perfect for the diagram and the original question.  I fear that streaming will have different buffering delays based on the end devices and therefore you won't be able to keep it in sync on all devices.  The fact is most guests will arrive in a vehicle that has a radio and speaker.  Nothing to install and no client buffering.  Also with a radio broadcast there will be no network connections for each device, which may impact the buffering delays...

Comment: But this solution works for mobile devices that don't have a AM/FM tuner.  Plus it fits the original question very well!   I just worry that the original concept hadn't thought through guests not willing to install applications on their device and the data stream buffering.

Comment: It's for a tight alley, not a country road, people won't come in cars. We've experienced this in previous years.. also, people already said they would gladly install an app :D

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram suggests that each device would be on your local WiFi, which means the guests would need to join your network.  That means they would need to know the SSID, there would be no need for a passphrase as you would need to publicly post the SSID and passphrase.  Then, unless you have created some DMZ for this musical network, anyone would have access to your network.

But the bigger issue is the act of streaming itself as there is device buffering with such things.  It would be near impossible to have the music sync'ed on the devices to any light display.

The best solution would be to broadcast over radio wave on an open channel.  Here are some starting points for that:
http://www.jpole-antenna.com/2013/10/11/broadcast-high-quality-music-for-your-holiday-lights-display/

https://sourcefmtransmitter.com/shop/category/christmas-lights-to-music/

- Good Luck!

Comment: Other solutions in this questions are good and I will try all of them, but this one I think fits the case the best. Therefore I will award you the bounty which ends today. Haven't had the time to test all solutions. So I have to go on gut / instinct to tell this is the best answer. Even though one of the other solutions might be better in hindsight, which is a luxury i don't have right now because the bounty will be awarded automatically in 12 hours. Thank you for all your suggestions and time!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the dev has already been done, there is an app "Speakerfy" that looks promising.
It is available on most of the mobile platforms and seems to do exactly what you need.
There is an article on this app at the following link that should give even more info.
http://techland.time.com/2013/04/01/speakerfy-a-free-app-for-whole-home-audio-or-silent-discos/
I hope this helps.

Comment: Speakerfy is great! Except that it does not allow the capture of audio, only preselected audio files.. Good suggestion but I think it does not quite fit the case.

Answer (score 0):

thinking about any device , i wold try get a Raspberry Pi (U$35) , install a Apache and Tomcat , Create a Web Application to play your musics  , get a nice and easy domain or get a free domain and that's it .
You will not need any one use your wifi (unless you want).
if you get Hacked its just a U$35 Raspberry Pi , make sure to have a backup of you stuffs .
Any device with web browser will do it .

Comment: I already have a Raspberry Pi setup, I'll try this solution ;)