# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2017/' failed: Invalid frame header

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, asyncsocket

I'm trying to make an async websocket server using c#.

I already have handshake completed, after searching a lot on the internet.
But after the handshake I can't seem to send any data in byte array format :(

This is the code i'm using to send byte[] data to the accepted and connected socket (I check both!)

```
socket.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello"));
//socket is a System.Net.Sockets.Socket object.
```

If i try to do this I get this on the client side (I use a chrome extension called "Simple Web Socket Client"):

```
index.js:15 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2017/' failed: Invalid frame header  
CLOSED: ws://localhost:2017
```

(Yes 2017 is the port), but why does it say Invalid frame

OK, i get that there is no frame header on the "hello" string, but i can't seem to find what the appropriate header is anywhere on the internet :( and YES I searched and all I get is a seriously confusing specification about RTC!

Anybody here know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure where you've looked but have a look at the ultimate source for websockets, i.e. the standard RFC 6455. [It describes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-27) how the framing is done. You are doing no framing at all in your sample code but just send the unframed data directly to socket (not websocket).

Comment: I know i'm not doing any framing, I didn't even know this was a thing until I got an error about it (welcome to programming :P), I just want to send byte[] audio packets to clients, but I don't know how to do so after the handshake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) or in the [webSocket specification itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), the webSocket protocol exchanges data in a specific data frame format.  You don't just write bytes to a plain socket.

Here's an example of what the frame format looks like:

```
 0               1               2               3              
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
|F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
|I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
|N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
| |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 4               5               6               7              
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
 8               9               10              11             
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
|                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
 12              13              14              15
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
+-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
:                     Payload Data continued ...                :
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|                     Payload Data continued ...                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You must put your data in this format and you must also use the security scheme based on the previously exchanged security credentials.  A webSocket is not a plain socket.  You must use the webSocket protocol.

FYI, my people don't implement webSocket endpoints from scratch, but rather pick up a library in your selected language that does all that work for you.  Then, you can just send bytes and the library will take care of the protocol work for you.

Comment: Okay thank you for the explanation! I saw this in the specification, but excuse me if this sounds stupid but I don't understand it at all.. how does this translate into code? Is the first row of numbers byte indices? It all seems to me like random numbers and characters '^-^

Comment: @ErikBrandsma - Why are you trying to implement the webSocket protocol from scratch?  Most people pick up a library that does all the protocol work for you and then you can just send what you want without worrying about all those details.  If you're going to implement a protocol from scratch, then you have to learn how to read RFC documents from scratch since those are the definitive reference on what is required in a protocol.  There's a lot involved in this protocol, including encryption.

Comment: I don't xD I just want to stream audio byte[] packets to clients. The goal is to stream windows sound (stereo mix) to clients, i already have the part where I get byte[] packets from the audio card, but now I want to send that data to clients, and sockets seemed to be the best option to do this

Comment: @ErikBrandsma - What kind of clients?  Browser clients?  Or what?  Browsers already support various audio streaming formats.

Comment: Smartphones, I'm gonna make an app, probably in hybrid form, so browser yeah :) I know there are libraries, but the project requires the audio to be played at the same time across all clients, there can be NO difference between them. A delay is OK as long as the delay is the same across clients. So for example, if the server streams the audio and the server is at 00:10 and all clients are at 00:07, that is OK :) know any streaming libraries that can help me achieve this goal?

Comment: @ErikBrandsma - We've answered your original question here.  If you want to ask a new question where you describe your actual high level problem, then I'd suggest you write a new question that describes your requirements in detail and what you're looking for help with.  Just keep in mind that asking for a 3rd party library that does something in particular is "off-topic" here for stack overflow and questions like that will be closed.  I see zero reason why you'd be using webSocket at all for this particular need.

Comment: I understand, I shall accept your answer as it does answer the question, just understand that this is very confusing :P my actual high level question is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395045/stream-audio-from-pc-to-smartphones

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. Solved by installing `socket.io at client side`. It may work for you too.